# What does GetObject() method return using LDAP?

Tags: c#, vbscript, active-directory

I am working on an intranet website that was created using VBS and Active Directory, and I have to remake a new version using C#. I'm having trouble understanding a VB method : `GetObject("LDAP://"+Groups)`.

Where `Groups = userObject.memberOf`

`Groups` are the groups a user belongs to. What would be the equivalent of this method in C#? And what exactly is being returned by this method?

What I have done so far is create a POCO called `ADProperties` which allows me to load user properties after searching a user. I have implemented authentication too, so I am using `ClaimsIdentity` to handle the user that's logged and have added Active Directory properties to those claims.

Thanks!

Comment: you should have a member of property which will be a list of groups in y our c# code too

Comment: @BugFinder Do you mean in my `ADProperties` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772325(v=vs.85).aspx, I would assume the method is used to get an array of the actual `Group` objects. You should be able to confirm this by checking what is further done with this object in your code.

There also doesn't seem to be an equivalent in C#, so you'll just have to figure out what this data is used for and find a different way to do it in c#. If you keep having trouble, post more of your code and where the problems arise.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I guess creating my own objects with the correct parameters is the way to go